# How can I clear a numeric editText in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, numeric

On my Android App there is a EditText which is supposed to keep numeric values; that's why I defined it as

```
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/TextNumb" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="right|center" android:maxLines="1"
 android:maxLength="10" android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal"/>
```

But at a certain point of my App I want to clear it, so in my Activity I call this EditText View and I write:

```
mEditView.setText("");
```

But I get a run-time error...how could I fix it? Is there a way to clean it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shan't get runtime error calling `mEditView.setText("");`. If you do, then you do something wrong outside this expression, and we need your code to tell what specifically. My guess would be  not initialized `mEditView` (`NullPointerException`) or calling `setText` on different thread than UI (`java.lang.RuntimeException`).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting it to `null`?

```
mEditView.setText(null);
```

Comment: Works, but setText("") should work too, so there's probably something else going on.